# Is it possible that a call to locals() will overload the memory?

Tags: python, memory, memory-leaks

I have python code that performs many operations on a big tiff image, including slicing, running through a segmentation network, extracting polygons from the segmentation masks, etc.

When running my script on a very large image I suddenly got a memory error and the program crashed.

I used muppy's [tracker module](https://pympler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/muppy.html#the-tracker-module) to try and find the source of the memory "leak", and was able to pinpoint it to the line:

```
if 'cls_contours' not in locals()
```

The diff showed that after calling this line (the condition was False so everything inside was skipped), I had an extra 5.76GB worth of numpy.ndarrays in my memory. This condition is meant to check whether `cls_contours` already exists, in which case it should not be calculated again because it takes a long time, and its existence depends on user input.

I substituted this condition with `if cls_contours is not None` after initializing it to `None` in the correct place. I ran it again and lo and behold, no more multiple GB of memory used, and the functionality remained the same.

My question is - is it possible that simply calling `locals()` required python to load into memory **all of the previously generated variables** within the namespace, including many segmentation maps? I would expect them to already be in the memory if they are in the namespace though so it doesn't make sense. What other explanation could there be?

Comment: It appears that you are confusing the function `local()` (whatever that is) with the Python built-in function `locals()`. But that of course could be a typo. Either way, modify your question.

Comment: I am skeptical of this, but just in general `if 'cls_contours' not in locals()` is a huge red flag. Your code should never have to do this outside of very niche circumstances

Comment: @BoarGules You are absolutely right, it is a typo (and a persistent one, too...). Fixed, thanks!

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga can you please explain why?

Comment: @OphirS because there is never a good reason to not know whether a variable is defined (again, outside of niche contexts like writing a debugger or something). In any case, can you add more details about your question? Basically, using `locals` creates a *new dict*, so it references each object one more time. I don't know any good reason why that would increase the memory, but can you tell us more (with details) about exactly what you are doing?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga in my case calculating this variable takes a lot of time, and there are different functions that might need it, depending on user input. Therefore, I only want to calculate it if necessary and to not recalculate it if it already exists.

Comment: @OphirS that doesn't make any sense. "variables" don't take memory, *objects* do. You should know, since you are writing the source code, whether or not a variable has been defined. Whether or not your large object is created is *irrelevant* to whether or not the variable is defined. Again, this screams bad design. There are various patterns for lazy-loading of objects, and they don't require a clunky check of the `locals()` dict. In any case, I am actually curious about your memory issue, if you can add more details

Comment: It’s better to initialize the variable `cls_contours` with the value `None` at the beginning of your program (or function). Then use `if cls_contours is None:` instead of abusing `locals()`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I didn't say that this variable takes up memory. I said that it takes time to calculate it. Other objects within the namespace take up memory, and I am wondering whether my call to `locals()` overloads the memory. I don't know if it exists because that depends on user input. I could create a condition based on the user input, but that feels too implicit, especially when this condition is complex.

Comment: Thanks for your explanations!
I'm happy to add more details, could you point me to the specific missing details you were referring to?

Comment: @OphirS ok, regardless, **you are conflating variables and objects**. Variables are *references to objects*. Your *object* takes a long time to create. The existence of a variable should *never* depend on user input, I suspected that you had some situation like that. Look, this is a *well known* anti-pattern. Variables shouldn't be created dynamically. But you are free to ignore my advice if you want.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I shall take your advice with both hands! Thank you so much for your responses, they were very helpful and enlightening. Already corrected my code based on your comments.